# Gatsby Error: TypeError [ ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-remark-image

I am following a youtube tutorial on Gatsby Bootcamp by Andrew Mead and up to 3:10:00 minutes
everything worked smoothly but as soon as I install `gatsby-remark-relative-images` and `gatsby-remark-images` plugin and add them to `gatsby-config.js` file to display images and when I run `npm run develop` I get an error like the one shown below.

[image]
Below is my gatsby-config.js file.

```html
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/
 */

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */

  siteMetadata:{
    title:'Gatsby Bootcamp',
    author:'Author'
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      resolve:'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options:{
        name: 'src',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      reslove: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options:{
        plugins:[
          'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
          {
            resolve:'gatsby-remark-images',
            options:{
              maxWidth:750,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation explains](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images/#to-convert-frontmatter-images), you must add the following snippet in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require('gatsby-remark-relative-images');

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node }) => {
  fmImagesToRelative(node);
};
```

This takes every node returned by your gatsby-source plugins and converts any absolute paths in markdown frontmatter data into relative paths if a matching file is found.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also had a simple spelling error. Instead of resolve I had reslove. It works fine now.